# I want to build a racetrack/waterslide with differently sized tracks/slides

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, bevel, path, curve-modifier

I want to build a racetrack/waterslide with variating track/slide sizes. The cross-section of the track/slide should be always the same, only that the part between them should be variable.

This is the top view of the track/slide. As you can see there even should be other "intersections".

[image: topview of slide/track]

This is its cross-section

[image: cross-section]

As you can see here, I already managed to get my track/slide along a path.
[image: slide/track]

This should demonstrate how the track/slide should have more space to the right side[image]

It's important that the track's/slide's walls should always be the same size. Only the area in between them should variate.

I don't know how to do so.
I could align the walls (left and right) along 2 splines marking the walls of the track, but just filling the gap between the faces will destroy the smooth surface?

Here is the example of what I was able to generate.[image]

This was done by creating a left and a right wall along 2 curves and a filled middle section with another closed curves area. But as you can see, the distance between the "walls" is uneven at the normal sections, the middle part isn't smooth and changing the paths direction (hight) doesn't look good at all.

Thank you very much for your help.
Greetings